# While showing ProgressDialog enable app functionality

Tags: android

While network call I am displaying Progress Dialog in my application. On current screen , I have three buttons. How can I enable these buttons while showing Progress Dialog? Is there any way to do this?

Is it possible to enable buttons while showing Progress Dialog?

Comment: try to write the progress dialog code in asynctask

Comment: Oops!i missread ur question.I dont think if u can do that coz when a dialog is invoked the activity moves to a paused state.Try using a view instead

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom dialog with folowwing xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressbar"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />
           <Button  android:layout_height="match_parent"  android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is just an example 
You can have a progress bar and a buttons that will be visible.